# How to rewrite a Canvas (reuse it)

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, surfaceview

i've got a method which draws an auto-generated set of lines onto a Canvas. This works without problems.
Now the question is, how to add e.g. lines on this Canvas with the onTouch event. I try to solve this with a Thread and a SurfaceView, but then the Thread draws the auto-generated set infinitely. 
(The lines i want to add have to be deletable).

Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: We can't reasonably answer this without seeing snippets of the code in question. Please edit your question to provide more detailed information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your **lines coordinates in arraylist** of line objects and use loop in your **onDraw** method iterate every line to draw it on canvas.
Add lines in arraylist onTouch.
After adding line onTouch call **invalidate()** to update canvas.

Comment: thanks, the invalidate() helped me a lot! But i've got about 100 lines to redraw every time if i want to remove the new object. Is it possible to save the first auto-generated "drawing" and then working on this Canvas, as it were a background-images?

Answer (score 1):

use

```
invalidate()
```

this will call

```
onDraw(Canvas canvas)
```